# Access cell object from defined name in SheetJS

Tags: sheetjs

I have named cells, which I can *see* after reading the file

```
let x = wb.Workbook.Names[0]
console.log(x)
->  { Name: 'my_name', Ref: 'datasheet!$B$6' }
```

how can I use the given ref now to access the cell?

Unfortunately `wb[x.Ref].v` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a method to do this but it can easily be achieved by doing something similar to:

```js
wb.getByRef = (ref) => {
    ref = ref.split('$');
    return wb[ref[1] + ref[2]]
}
```

And then using it like this:

```js
let x = wb.Workbook.Names[0];

const value = wb.getByRef(x.ref).v;

console.log(value) // Log the value at the x-cell
```